# Syntax ERROR inside MySQL TRIGGER -> Insert Into Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger that inserts new row into another table however there is an error somewhere as it tells me my values are NULL and they are not or at least they are not suppose to be.

**Code of a TRIGGER**

Delimiter //

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_active_user AFTER UPDATE ON `pre_reg`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentUser INT;
    DECLARE banned INT;
    DECLARE user_type INT;
    DECLARE username VARCHAR (25);
    DECLARE password VARCHAR (60);
    DECLARE usersince datetime;
    DECLARE email varchar(40);
    SET @currentUser := (select `id` FROM `pre_reg` WHERE `active` = 1);
    SET @banned = 0;
    SET @user_type = 3;
    SET @username := (select `username` FROM `pre_reg` WHERE `id` = currentUser);
    SET @password := (select `password` FROM `pre_reg` WHERE `id` = currentUser);
    SET @usersince := (select `date` FROM `pre_reg` WHERE `id` = currentUser);
    SET @email := (select `email` FROM `pre_reg` WHERE `id` = currentUser);
    INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (@currentUser, @username, @password);
END//
Delimiter ;
```

I even tried hard coding in the value of a currentUser in SET username, password, email SET statements. However It doesn't work I get following error:

**Error**

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null

I even tried to enter only ID (@currentUser) to make sure its set and the rest was hard coded (Works fine! So I assume that error is in the SET statements but can't figure out what it tells me always that value is NULL

**This is how I have created the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `pre_reg` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `authentication` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `active` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
GO
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
`username` VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
`banned` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`user_since` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
GO
```

Comment: If this is an after update trigger, why not use `new`?

Comment: Updated the question with table, also @Gordon what do you mean NEW? I am as you can tell NEW :) at this so not sure what you mean! Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: He is saying that there exists OPERANDS (NEW and OLD) to use alongside triggers to use the values that you update/insert/delete, you dont need to query then see it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
Delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER new_active_user AFTER UPDATE ON `pre_reg`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`)
        VALUES (new.id, new.username, new.password);
END//
Delimiter ;
```

It inserts into the `users` table whatever what just updated in `pre_reg`.

Comment: I will try this ... Will let you know thank you for helping me and explaining the operand NEW (weather it works in my situation or not at least I have learnt something new) THANK YOU!

Comment: This worked however it throws me an error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error... But it did everything I asked new rows were created

Comment: @theStudent . . . Hmmm, if the database is actually being modified, then the trigger is running.  That suggests the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time and help, greatly appreciated Gordon! I will keep looking!